# Montar URL sem aparecer o nome da Action ou da Controller ou ambas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Quem tem experiência em e-*commerce*, sabe o que vou perguntar. Normalmente, quando criamos uma rota, e chamamos nossa Action relacionada a essa rota, a URL é montada assim:

http://minha_pagina.com.br/Home/Minha_Action/

Caso haja parâmetros, então é carregado após o nome da Action. O que eu estou precisando é saber se há como eu não mostrar o nome da Controller (no meu exemplo, Home) e nem o nome da Action, apenas um parâmetro, que seria o nome do produto, como acontece com e-*commerce*, tipo assim:

http://www.e-commerce.com.br/tv-samsung-52-ultra-slin-cor-preta

Ou seja, após a barra, mostrar somente os parâmetros da rota. Tem como, usando MVC 5?

Caso não seja possível, dar conviver com o nome da controller, mas o Action gostaria de retirar.

Comment: você sabe como o site funciona? Favor indicar quando encontrar uma resposta que resolva seu problema, marcando a mesma como solução (clicando no ícone do "certo" logo abaixo do score da resposta)

Answer (score 6):

Esta descrição que fica após o endereço é chamada de *slug*. Neste caso, o que você precisa fazer é um manipulador específico de rota. Por exemplo:

### AppStart\RouteConfig.cs

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new MeuManipuladorDeRota();
```

### Infrastructure\MeuManipuladorDeRota.cs

```cs
public class MeuManipuladorDeRota : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var url = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.TrimStart('/');

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            ItemDePagina item = GerenciadorDeRedirecionamento.ObterPaginaPorUrl(url);
            if (item != null)
            {
                MontarRequisicao(item.Controller, 
                    item.Action ?? "Index", 
                    item.ConteudoId .ToString(), 
                    requestContext);
            }
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }

    private static void MontarRequisicao(string controller, string action, string id, RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }

        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = action;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = id;
    }
}
```

### ViewModels\ItemDePagina.cs

```cs
public class ItemDePagina {
    public String Controller { get; set; }
    public String Action { get; set; }
    public int ConteudoId { get; set; }
}
```

### Infrastructure\GerenciadorDeRedirecionamento.cs

```cs
public static class GerenciadorDeRedirecionamento
{
    public static ItemDePagina ObterPaginaPorUrl(string url)
    {
        ItemDePagina item = null;

        /* Aqui você pesquisa na entidade pela descrição, passando o parâmetro url. */
        /* Este é o ponto mais importante da lógica, que é onde você vai pesquisar o item de acordo com as suas regras de negócio. */
        /* Depois você monta um objeto ItemDePagina (no caso, item) e o devolve. */

        return item;
    }
}
```